# Applying MongoDB patch to in-memory object in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I want to apply changes on a C# object from a `mongodb` like update definition. For example lets say I have the following code:

```
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization;
using MongoDB.Driver;

class Program
{
    class Employee
    {
        public string LastName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        public string FirstName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Employee employee = new Employee()
        {
            LastName = "ln",
            FirstName = "test"
        };

        var def = Builders<Employee>.Update.Set("LastName", "ln1");
        def = def.Set("FirstName", "another");
        var registry = BsonSerializer.SerializerRegistry;
        var serializer = registry.GetSerializer<Employee>();
        var patch = def?.Render(serializer, registry).ToString() ?? string.Empty;
        //TODO: How do I apply this "patch" to employee object?
    }
}
```

After executing I have patch as:

```
{ "$set" : { "LastName" : "ln1", "FirstName" : "another" } }
```

Now, how do I apply this update definition to the `employee` object? Note that I dont have any real database and these are just C# objects.

Answer (score 0):

An update operation might not update only one element, it will update every element that matches the filter (which you are missing).

If you still want to update multiple elements, I don't think you can get the updated items easily. You would have to query the ID of all updated items, and manually replace them in memory.

But, if you want to update a single element and also update the one you have in memory, you need to use the "ReplaceOne" method. With that said, your code would change slightly:

```
static void UpdateEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    var client = new MongoClient("MongoConnectionString");

    var database = client.GetDatabase("ClusterName");

    var collection = database.GetCollection<Employee>("Employee");

    employee.FirstName = "Another";
    employee.LastName = "ln1";

    collection.ReplaceOne(new BsonDocument("_id", employee.Id.ToString()), employee, new ReplaceOptions() { IsUpsert = true });
}
```

Note that I have added a property called "Id" to the employee class, but you can use whatever you need to filter it.

If you need more help creating a database, you can follow this tutorial: https://intodot.net/creating-and-connecting-to-a-mongodb-atlas-cluster/